# pdftops eps font issue

Tags: linux, pdf, adobe-illustrator, eps

I'm creating a pdf with Apache FOP in Linux
then I need to convert the pdf it into an eps.

I'm trying lot of ways, the only one that seems works is the pdftops.
But,
when I convert it into Linux in command line

```
pdftops file.pdf -eps file.eps
```

This command creates me the eps
but when I try to open it in Adobe Illustrator in Windows XP
It returns me the error

```
EAAFD+HelveticaNeueLTStd-MdCnO_99-Identify-H;
Font not found on the system; missing font has been substituted.
```

But
1: the fonts han not been substituted
2: the eps do not show words inside it is all blank instead of the images

I'm sure that in Windows XP I have all the fonts
becouse if I convert the pdf to an eps inside the Adobe Illustrator
all works fine and Adobe Illustrator do not show me the fonts issue.

Can you help me?
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If something is not working as intended, then that's a bug clear and simple: it needs to be *debugged* and *fixed*.  Please could you file a bug-report at:

- [launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+filebug](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+filebug?field.title=pdftoeps+failing+on+embedded+Helvetica+Neue)

along with a copy of the PDF file that is being generated, and the exact command that is being used for the conversion (particularly whether it is `pdf2ps` (part of GhostScript), or `pdfteps` (part of Poppler/Xpdf and found in the [`poppler-utils`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/poppler-utils) package).

*(Note that this question has been asked in [three](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2011-July/thread.html#247940) [other](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/874427) [places](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-fop-users/201107.mbox/browser), but not yet reported in the bug-tracker where it can be explored, pointed to the right people and hopefully fixed).*

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your setup, it looks like you're asking FOP to draw your text using the Helvetica Neue font, which is not part of the [standard set of PDF fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29) (note that *Helvetica* is, but not Helvetica Neue).

It would seem to me that your two options are to either force FOP to use Helvetica instead of Helvetica Neue, or force it to embed Helvetica Neue into the PDF (pdf2ps *should* automatically embed it into the result EPS file). In the first instance, you shouldn't need embedding at all, while in the second case the file should be embedded.

More info on how FOP handles fonts is also available from [the package's documentation](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html)—as you can see, Helvetica Neue is not listed here.

Comment: I would verify that FOP is, in fact, [embedding the font](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html#autodetect) (you can see if the font is embedded from Acrobat or Illustrator). PDF2PS should embed the fonts automatically.

Comment: I've already tried the PDF2PS command.
But it creates a .ps with low quality.
(and I think that for this reason it do not embed fonts)

Do you have another suggestion? Or a practical example of this?